# How to write subscripts in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

*How can one write subscripts in an Isabelle (2021) `text` command?*

I tried to use the `<^sub>` symbol (which automatically converts to a down arrow) as follows:

```
text ‹
identity 1<^sub>S
›
```

but it gives an error:

```
Undefined document antiquotation: "sub"⌂
```

I also tried the LaTex way and used underscore `_`, but jEdit does not seem to recognize LaTex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the antiquotation `text`:

```
text ‹
identity \<^text>‹1⇩S›
›
(*or simply*)
text‹identity ‹1⇩S››
```

For further information about the command `text` see subsection 4.1 in the official documentation (*The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual* or Isar-ref) of Isabelle2021, for further information about the antiquotation `text` see section 4.2 in the official documentation (Isar-ref) of Isabelle2021.

> I also tried the LaTex way and used underscore _, but jEdit does not
> seem to recognize LaTex.

Further, please note that, in general, LaTeX output is generated while processing a session, and it is possible to augment theory files with arbitrary LaTeX source code like so:

```
text‹identity $1_S$›
```

In this case, `$1_S$` should appear in the generated LaTeX documents, as expected. However, of course, jEdit will display this as raw LaTeX. For further information see the document *The Isabelle/Isar Implementation* (part of the official Isabelle2021 documentation) and, possibly, *LaTeX Sugar for Isabelle Documents* (also part of the official Isabelle2021 documentation).

Comment: Shortcut in Isabelle/jEdit: C-e Downarrow